# Why do I have to include extra type information in this function

Tags: scala

I'm trying to refresh a bit of Scala during my spare time. My question, why do I have to annotate 'size' with the polymorphic type `A` here. I'm not interested in that information when I'm calculating the size of a tree. Nonetheless the Scala compiler forces me to write it like this:

```
def size[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = {
    t match {
      case Leaf => 1
      case Branch(l,r) => 1 + size(l) + size(r)
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
def size(t: Tree): Int = {
    t match {
      case Leaf => 1
      case Branch(l,r) => 1 + size(l) + size(r)
    }
}
```

Context of this function:

```
package fpinscala.datastructures

sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

object Tree {

  def size[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = {
    t match {
      case Leaf => 1
      case Branch(l,r) => 1 + size(l) + size(r)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I guess because Tree is defined as Tree[something], and not just Tree?

Comment: Scala doesn't allow raw types, as in Java. In Java, it causes only a warning like `List l = new ArrayList<>()`, but in Scala, an equivalent would cause a compilation error. Scala is thus more strict.

Comment: Then why do I have to repeat the polymorphic type in both the function name size[A] and also the parameters. It feels like boilerplate to me.

Comment: Where is your `size` method defined? Does its wrapping class already mention the `A` parameter? If the class already defines it, then you should be good with: `def size(t: Tree[A])`

Comment: @Mik378 I added the entire listing now. It's defined inside a companion object I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First notice that your function has a problem:

```
case Leaf => 1
```

Matches on equality with the `Leaf` companion object and not on the case class; you should write instead:

```
case Leaf(_) => 1
```

Then you can resort to wildcard existential types to avoid the type:

```
def size(t: Tree[_]): Int = {
  t match {
    case Leaf(_) => 1
    case Branch(l,r) => 1 + size(l) + size(r)
  }
}
```

Also notice that your size function will count also the number of branches and I think it more likely that you just want to count leafs; in that case change it to:

```
case Branch(l,r) => size(l) + size(r)
```

Counting branches:

```
size(Branch(Branch(Leaf(1),Leaf(2)),Leaf(3))) = 5
```

Counting leafs:

```
Branch(Branch(Leaf(1),Leaf(2)),Leaf(3)) = 3
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way in Scala. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comments, you have this:

```
object Tree {

  def size[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = {  //you would want to avoid specifying the first [A]
    t match {
      case Leaf => 1
      case Branch(l,r) => 1 + size(l) + size(r)
    }
  }

}
```

Notice that a companion object doesn't involve a generic type, so **you have to specify it on its method(s)**, otherwise the compiler would search for a `A` class (while parsing the `size`'s parameters), that obviously doesn't exist.
You want to tell the compiler: **A is meant to be a generic type, not a particular one**!

So it's not really a boilerplate, it's what the compiler requires and it seems perfectly logical.